# how to add user's extra profile information apart from email and password in firebase?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication, angularfire2

I'm using firebase with angular4 with the angularfire2 library. After signing up user with email and password I can see the user has been registered in the database in firebase. However I cannot add extra fields like name, address, etc. I thought of creating a ('/users') list then use the user's Uid to store user profile information. But the document says I can assign "name" and "profile picture". If that's the case I cannot add any field to the users database from authentication.

Comment: Please include a code sample showing what you've tried and any errors you saw. Have you read the documentation on user profiles? https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile

Comment: @Travis Christian thanks for your reply. yes i was following firebase documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.UserInfo. i can see the signed up users in authetication section. what i am wondering is firebase docs shows that i can add user name and upload a picture. but it seems like there are no fields of name and number in the authentication section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mention, by the firebase documentation, you can do it by using angularfire2 like this:

```
  this.af.auth.createUser({
    email: <UserEmail>,
    password: <UserPass>
  }).then(
    (success) => {
    success.auth.updateProfile({
        displayName: <UserName>,
        photoURL: <UserPhotoURLString>
      })
      .then(res => console.log("profile updated"))
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }).catch(
    (err) => {
    console.log(err);
  })
```

as you can see in the code attach above, after you use the built-in method of `af.auth.createUser` you receive as promise an User object, and after that you can use another built-in method `success.auth.updateProfile` to update the User Profile area in the firebase authetication section.
This code worked for me perfectly, so just adjust this to your code and that it :) enjoy.

Comment: But this approach just works for adding displayname and photoUrl.  For other fields would have create another collection and make joint with UID?

Answer (score 0):

AngularFire2 has a new version of the update. You can try out this code for the new angularfire version.

```
this.afAuth.auth.currentUser.updateProfile({
          displayName: 'your profile name',
          photoURL: 'your pic url'
        }).then(() => {
          console.log('DisplayName updated')
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

You can use this code for update user date when you logged in.

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to figure this one out and I couldn't find any recent answers for the latest firebase version. So I hope this solution works for you too.

The trick for me was I had to add an `await` on the update profile and make the function `async`.

The benefits for this is that you can use the firebase user object that you can store in your `localStorage` or `sessionStorage` and you can easily reference the information you need from there instead of creating a new document that you always have to query.

```
  SignUp(user, password) {
    return this.afAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(user.email, password)
      .then(async (result) => {
        /* Call the SendVerificaitonMail() function when new user sign
        up and returns promise */
        this.SendVerificationMail();

        await result.user?.updateProfile({
          displayName: user.name+ ' '+ user.surname,
          photoURL: "https://example.com/jane-q-user/profile.jpg"
        }).then(() => {

          this.SetUserData(result.user, user);
          this.ngZone.run(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['home']);
          });

        }).catch((error) => {
          // An error occurred
          // ...
        });

      }).catch((error) => {
        window.alert('Something wrong with Signup  '+error.message);
      });
  }
```